# Transform 2 very similar functions in to one

Tags: angular, typescript, function

I have these two functions, which are very very similar :

```js
setEndTimes(pricerules: PriceRule[]) {
    this.endTimes = [];
    pricerules.forEach(pricerule => {
      this.endTimes.push({
        hour: Number(pricerule.endTime.split(':')[0]),
        minute: Number(pricerule.endTime.split(':')[1])
      });
    });
  }

  setStartTimes(pricerules: PriceRule[]) {
    this.startTimes = [];
    pricerules.forEach(pricerule => {
      this.startTimes.push({
        hour: Number(pricerule.startTime.split(':')[0]),
        minute: Number(pricerule.startTime.split(':')[1])
      });
    });
  }
```

How to transform these 2 functions into one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would dynamic properties for this case like:

```
setTimes(pricerules: PriceRule[], _times: string) {
    this[`${_times}s`] = [];
    pricerules.forEach(pricerule => {
      this[`${_times}s`].push({
        hour: Number(pricerule[_times].split(':')[0]),
        minute: Number(pricerule[_times].split(':')[1])
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: did you mean `this.[_times]=[]` ?

Comment: yep that's what I've meant

Comment: the call of this function is `this.setTimes(priceRules, 'endTimes');` ?

Comment: @Fealo yes generally the aproach is like that

Comment: ok I see  its becase endTimes and endTime. I ve updated the code but you have to call func this.setTimes(priceRules, 'endTime') without s

Comment: yes, a third parameter ? Or maybe you have a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor the code which projects the array from `pricerules` into a function and set the properties and use [`bracket notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the object property.

```
setEndTimes(pricerules: PriceRule[]) {
    this.endTimes = returnTimes(pricerules, 'endTime');
}

setStartTimes(pricerules: PriceRule[]) {
    this.startTimes = returnTimes(pricerules, 'startTime');
}

returnTimes(pricerules, time) {
    return pricerules.map(x => (
    {
                    hour: Number(x[time].split(':')[0]),
                    minute: Number(x[time].split(':')[1])
    }));
}
```